# How to deploy javascript project with jenkins?

Tags: javascript, tomcat, jenkins

I am using Jenkins to deploy my java webapps. Now I have a pure javascript project (build with gulp).  How to deploy that with jenkins on a tomcat server? Building javascript  projects works like a charm on Jenkins and deploying also as long as they are part of a java project (.war).

Is there either a way to write shell script to deploy a pure js project or Jenkins plugin to do that? I don't want to do the deploy configuration inside the project files, like using a gulp taks.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this node [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jenkins) to make it work.

```
var jenkins = require('gulp-jenkins');

jenkins.init({
  username: 'Agent_007',
  password: 'golden_gun',
  url: 'jenkins.your-site.com'
});

gulp.task('build production', function() {
  return gulp.src('./*')
    .pipe(jenkins.build('Secret_App', {
      target_env: 'prod',
      tag_name: 'tags/v0.07/trunk',
    }));
});
```

Comment: But isn't that a gulp task? So I couldn't configure the target server from jenkins? Or am I misunderstanding something?